# How can i calculate daily growth rate based on the last seven days in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, dataset

I have this dataset and I want to calculate the **daily growth rate** from **cu_deaths column** based on the last seven days. Any idea?
In `dplyr` if possible:

dput:

```
structure(list(Country.Region = c("Greece", "Greece", "Greece", 
"Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece"), date = structure(c(1586577600, 
1586664000, 1586750400, 1586836800, 1586923200, 1587009600, 1587096000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), confirmed = c(70, 
33, 31, 25, 22, 15, 17), death = c(1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3), recovered = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cu_cases = c(2081, 2114, 2145, 2170, 2192, 
2207, 2224), cu_deaths = c(93, 98, 99, 101, 102, 105, 108), days_elapsed = c(21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27), end_label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Greece"), index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can you use `dput` to show the example and also the expected output based on the input

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution to calculate the percentage growth per day:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(diff_deaths = cu_deaths - lag(cu_deaths),
         diff_day = 1,
         percent_growth = ((diff_deaths/diff_day)/cu_deaths*100))
```

If you also want to see the average daily growth by week, you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df$date <- ymd(df$date)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(diff_deaths = cu_deaths - lag(cu_deaths),
         diff_day = 1,
         percent_growth = ((diff_deaths/diff_day)/cu_deaths*100),
         week_number = isoweek(date)) %>%
  group_by(week_number) %>%
  mutate(weekly_avg_growth = mean(percent_growth))
```

Comment: Thanks, and if i want to calculate growth rate averaged by week?

Comment: No problem. I edited the answer above. If you feel that this has answered your question, feel free to click on the green check to accept the answer.